# Checking if an ArrayList exists in a map

Tags: java, arraylist, maps

My football team has 5 different teams and I am trying to make a program to keep a track of which players are registered with each team. I want to be able to add a new player but first the program checks if that player is already registered. I would also be able to add new teams in the future and again I would like to check if that team already exists.

I have made a Map variable with

`private Map<String, List<Player>> teamName;`

then initialised this in the constructor

`teamName = new HashMap<>();`

I then have a method to add new teams and new players, I want the method to check if the Club name already exists and then if it does exist, add the player name to that Club. if it doesn't exist then I want the program to add a new Club and then add that player to that club.

So far I have a method for adding a new player,

```
public void newPlayer(String club, Player name) {
}
```

I am not sure how I now go about checking that an ArrayList exists for `club` and if it does add `name` to this list, if `club` does not exist then I want to make a new list and add `name` to it.

if I then run the program and write,

```
Player jamesAtkinson = new Player();

newPlayer("first team", jamesAtkinson);
```

it would check if there is a List in the Map called 'first team' and then either add James Atikinson to it, or create a new List called first team and then add James Atkinson.

Is this even possible to do?

Comment: first learn the basics. Player James Atkinson = new Player(); will never compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are a few problems with code you've provided in the question. What you're looking for is the `.containsKey` function that hangs off of the Map interface.

```
if (players.containsKey("first team") {
     // Do something
} else {
     List<Player> firstTeam = new ArrayList<>();
     firstTeam.add(jamesAtikson);
     players.put("first team", jamesAtikson);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, that all makes sense, but if the List already exists then how do we add to it? ie, if I make a team called firstTeam and player JamesAtkinson, the list won't exist yet so it will be created, then I want to add another player to firstTeam. I know I need to write code in the first part of the `if` statement, idealy I want the list name to be that referenced by `String club` so I can then do something like `club.add(name);` not sure if this is possible though cause if I try it it says there is an error cannot find method `add(Player) Thanks James

Comment: @JoePasquale Then you need to call the `get` method on the Map and then call `add` on the returned list. You can even chain the methods together